# Python matplotlib subplot change y spine, ticks and label color

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

I have created a plot function that produces common x and multiple y-axes. It is working fine. I am having trouble setting the y-axes label, ticks, and edge to plot color.

#### Created plot function

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/color/named_colors.html
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors



def oscilloscope_plot(df,x='x',y=['y1','y2'],xlbl = ['xlabel','xuni'],
                      ylbl = [['ylabel1','yuni1'],['ylabel2','yuni2']],
                      saveformat='Oscilloscope_plot.jpg'):
    color_list = list(mcolors.TABLEAU_COLORS)
    n = len(y)
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=n,ncols=1,sharex=True)
    for i in range(n):
        # print('%s'%(y[i][0]))
        axes[i] = plt.subplot((n*100)+10+(i+1))
        plt.plot(df[x], df[y[i]],'-',color=color_list[i])
        axes[i].grid(axis="y")
        axes[i].legend(['%s'%(ylbl[i][0])])
        # axes[i].set_ylabel('(in %s)'%(ylbl[i][1]), color=color_list[i])
        axes[i].spines['left'].set_color(color_list[i])
        axes[i].tick_params(axis='y', color=color_list[i])
        plt.ylabel('(in %s)'%(ylbl[i][1]), color=color_list[i])
        if i==0:
            axes[i].spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
        elif i!=(n-1):
            plt.setp(axes[i].get_xaxis(), visible=False)
            axes[i].spines['top'].set_visible(False)
            axes[i].spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
            # axes[i].spines['left'].set_edgecolor(color_list[i])
            # axes[i].tick_params(axis='y', color=color_list[i])
        else:
            plt.setp(axes[i].get_xaxis(), visible=True)
            axes[i].spines['top'].set_visible(False)
            axes[i].spines['bottom'].set_visible(True)
            axes[i].set_xlabel('%s (in %s)'%(xlbl[0],xlbl[1]))
            # axes[i].spines['left'].set_edgecolor(color_list[i])
            # axes[i].tick_params(axis='y', color=color_list[i])
    plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.01)
    plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.12, right=0.97, top=0.95, bottom=0.15)
    temp_name = 'sun_inverterDCparams.png'
    plt.savefig(temp_name,bbox_inches='tight',pad_inches=0.1, dpi=250)
    plt.show()
```

#### Actual code

```
xdf = pd.DataFrame({'x':[10,20,30,40,50],'y1':[10,20,30,40,50],'y2':[10,20,30,40,50]})

oscilloscope_plot(xdf,x='x',y=['y1','y2'],xlbl=['X','x'],
                  ylbl=[['Y1','Y2'],['y1','y2'],['y1','y2']])
```

#### Present output:

In the below plot, I want to change the color of y axes ticks, label and spines to plot color.

[image]

Comment: I have run your code and checked it. I'll share it on [Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1_nwoBWvPTosYRBWQpfUoIFC6tzjXjz8b?usp=sharing). What would you like to modify further? Do you have the output you are expecting?

Comment: Colab's matplotlib version is the latest 3.5.1

Comment: you forgot `labelcolor`: `axes[i].tick_params(axis='y', color=color_list[i], labelcolor=color_list[i])`

Comment: @r-beginners yes! it worked. It is weird that I am getting different plots. For this example, perfectly fine and it is giving a solution as in `colab` which I heard the first time. Thanks for it. I hope it is not public and you will be deleting it. But, on my original data frame data, it is not working. I am in full surprise. Don't know why?